# Is There A System Variable for Application/Project Name?

Tags: .net, settings

I have a common code library between two projects in a single VB.NET Visual Studio 2017 (.NET 4.5.2) solution that must save their project settings to different locations.

In my `Common.My.Settings`, I have several `Application` settings such as:

```
DefaultAppDataPath = %CommonApplicationData%MyCompanyName\MyProductName\AppData.dat
```

What I'd like is (something like):

```
DefaultAppDataPath = %CommonApplicationData%MyCompanyName%ProductName%AppData.dat
```

This means I don't have to explicitly set the path; settings will simply be saved to either (say)

```
C:\Program Data\MyCompanyName\ThisProductName\AppData.dat
```

or

```
C:\Program Data\MyCompanyName\ThatProductName\AppData.dat
```

I've searched high and low but I can't find out whether there is a variable that will act as *%ProductName%* (or *%ProjectName%*, etc).

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a library should make decisions on where to store data itself - that is a setting that should be owned by the calling application. To start with you could use a simple static property exposed by the library that is set by the falling application at startup.

But if you still want to let the library resolve the name of the calling application, it's possible:

```
var programName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName.Split(',').First()
```

Comment: The library isn't making decisions in this case; it's serving two different products/projects in the same solution (they share a lot of code in this Common project which is a class library within the two products). The default name of a SQLite database contains settings that must be in different files, so the two consuming apps actually dictate the default file path. In the end I found that I was already manipulating the setting - refer my own answer.

Comment: The library probably shouldn't assume that `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` won't return null.  At least, if it's a general-purpose library.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my question was a bit of a furphy; I found that I was already manipulating the `DefaultAppDataPath`  setting, but mistakenly thought that %CommonApplicationData% was an actual Environment path variable. (I wrote the original code a few years ago. That's my excuse, anyway.)

In fact, I was parsing the setting and replacing *%CommonApplicationData%* with the actual `CommonApplicationData` environment value. So I just extended that to work with *%ProductName%*:

I'll leave the question up in case someone else needs to do the same thing. And here's my VB.NET code:

```
        _defaultAppDataPath = My.Settings.DefaultAppDataPath
        If _defaultAppDataPath.Contains("%"c) Then
            Dim sSections As String() = _defaultAppDataPath.Split({"%"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            If sSections.Count > 0 Then
                sSections(0) = Environment.GetFolderPath(CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Environment.SpecialFolder), sSections(0)), Environment.SpecialFolder))
                If sSections.Count > 1 Then sSections(2) = gsProductName
                _defaultAppDataPath = Path.Combine(sSections)
            End If
        End If
```

You can obviously extend this as you wish to take care of, say, product versions, different paths, etc.